# Can a global .gitconfig file be nested multiple layers deep?

Tags: git, git-config

All the examples I've seen of global .gitconfig files look something like this:

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = example@email.com

[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
```

I've never seen a [header] nested within another [header] before. Something like this:

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = example@email.com
    [foo]
        bar = baz
```

Is this possible in some circumstance? Can a global .gitconfig file be nested multiple layers deep?

Comment: Are searching for just an answer "no"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for Git configuration files is a modified INI-file syntax.

Some modified-INI-file-syntaxes ([or *syntaces*, if you want to fake up an English plural from Greek roots](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65541/180540)) allow that sort of nesting, but Git's does not.

In the Git form:

```
[top "middle"]
    bottom = value
```

represents the `git config` construct:

```
git config top.middle.bottom value
```

(add `--global` or `--file` directives to choose a file to set).  This is as close as we get to nesting.  You'll see these with multiple `remote` definitions, for instance:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

in the local `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible in some circumstance?

No.

It's always "possible". You can write your own parser or patch `git` to support such strange convention.

> Can a global .gitconfig file be nested multiple layers deep?

No.

The format is a [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Whitespace). [Leading whitespaces are ignored](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/config.c#L567), so `<space><space><tab>[foo]` is the same as just `[foo]` and will introduce new section.